# Edit a List<Tuple> item

Tags: c#, list, tuples

With a `List<String>` you can edit an item simply with this:

```
var index = List.FindIndex(s => s.Number == box.Text);
List[index] = new String;
```

But, how to apply it on a `List<Tuple<string, string>>` for example?

Comment: @MattBurland there's no extension `Number` for `s` with a `List<Tuple>` .. but apparently with `AD.Net`'s solution i have to use s.item1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var tuple = List.Find(s => s.Item1 == box.Text); 
//assuming you're searching for the first string, but you can change the predicate anyway. 
tuple = new Tuple<string, string>(new String, tuple.Item2);
```

As mentioned in the other answer, you can of course use the index too, but you can also just find the object and update it, that should work as well.

Comment: That did not change the list for me. It just created a local variable that was thrown away.

Comment: below answer worked for me, this one just created a local vairable

Answer (score 18):

You can find the index in a similar way - by applying a condition to each tuple from the list:

```
var index = listOfTuples.FindIndex(t => t.Item1 == box1.Text || t.Item2 == box2.Text);
```

You can replace an item by calling `Tuple.Create`:

```
listOfTuples[index] = Tuple.Create(box3.Text, box4.Text);
```

Comment: This worked fine for me, `Tuple.Create` is what i was needing